# Get type of django model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I'm writing some schema tests for django, using django's wrapper of the `unittest` framework.

I want to check that a field is always going to be `DateTimeField`, rather than `DateField`. So I attempted the following:

```
class TestSuite(TestCase):
    def test_for_correct_datetype(self):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(Obj.time, models.DateTimeField))
```

Because previously:

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    ....
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Note: There were several answers that said to use `getattr`, and it doesn't work for me either.

How can I make the `self.assertTrue()` work?

Comment: Hint: if you want to check type, maybe use the [`assertIsInstance` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field) method from the Model _meta API:

```
from django.db import models

class TestSuite(TestCase):
    def test_for_correct_datetype(self):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(Obj._meta.get_field('time'), models.DateTimeField))
```